# How to create dynamic session using Socket-Rocket Library

Tags: python, ios, sockets, websocket

I am trying to implement a chat application where i want to create dynamic session based on user names. It's a peer-peer chat app.

For example: If user A want to chat with user B, so on the server side this should create an instance and user B should have access to this instance.
Currently socket rocket chatserver.py file only listens to ip address/chat and form the iOS app i have to go to the same url to pass on the message to the other connected clients.

But instead of broadcasting it to everyone i want to create some thing i can control based on user names.

Any idea or links to share.